# Revert to default window theme in Cinnamon

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus, cinnamon

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 which comes with GNOME. Since I wanted to have the Windows task bar feel **with no item grouping**, I opted to install Cinnamon.

In Cinnamon, I lost the default Ubuntu feel and color theme. In particular, the default close:maximize:minimize icons that come with Ubuntu are gone (refer to below picture). How can I get those back?

I have explored countless themes using **Preferences > Themes > Add/Remove**, then choosing the appropriate window "feel" from **Preferences > Themes > Window borders**.

Here is a picture that shows the window appearance for both Nautilus and an arbitrary utility under Preferences **taken at the same time**.

GNOME (default) window feel vs window feel on Cinnamon:
[image: GNOME (default) window feel vs window feel on Cinnamon]

I want to get back the GNOME (Default) feel. Somehow Nautilus maintains the default window feel but all other windows do not.

Comment: Cinnamon is the default desktop for Mint and uses Nemo to control the desktop while Ubuntu uses nautilus. These are two completely different desktops. Choose one or the other, not goodtimes having both at he same time.

Comment: @beertempest Aha, this makes sense!